# how to access user entered information in html which is showing through web view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display html in android activity through web view,my screen will be like [image: webview]

spinner contains all HTML files template. 
when user enter First name ,last name & clicks on spinner ,took any html that entered first name & last name should display on HTML ...
how to do this in android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interaction with WebViews and native code you can bind the two via a `JavaScriptInterface`

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript